# Binding Data To DropDownList MVC Razor

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu, bind

I have just started with my project using MVC and Razor. Now I am encountering a problem when it comes to binding data coming from the database to a dropdownlist. Please refer on my codes below:

Specialization Model:

```
public class SpecializationModel
{
    [Display(Name = "SpecializationID")]
    public string SpecializationID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "SpecializationDescription")]
    public string SpecializationDescription { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
    public int SelectedSpecializationID { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Physicians()
{
    SpecializationManager spec = new SpecializationManager();
    List<Specialization> SpecializationList = spec.GetAllSpecialization();

    var obj = new SpecializationModel();

    obj.Items = new[]
    {
        foreach(var x in SpecializationList)
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = x.SpecializationID.ToString(), Text = x.SpecializationDescription };
        }
    };

    return View(obj);
}
```

I have this manager which contains my LINQ query to extract the data from the database.
I encounter problems on the controller. Wherein the error points on the `foreach` syntax saying `Invalid expression term foreach`

Can anyone please point me to the right direction? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

I have this code now without errors on the foreach part (thanks to the post below which I combined with what I have above). However, I can't seem to make the last line work. It produces an error about implicit cast:

```
var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var x in SpecializationList)
{
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = x.SpecializationID.ToString(), Text = x.SpecializationDescription });
}

obj.Items = items.ToList();
```

Please do help me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yopu can't put a foreach in a constructor, try:

```
var items = new List<SelectListItem >();
foreach(var x in SpecializationList)
{
           items.add(new SelectListItem { Value = x.SpecializationID.ToString(), Text = x.SpecializationDescription });
}

obj.Items = items;
```

**Edited**

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. But your code seems to have errors. 
On the `items.Add(x)` part, the compiler says that it has some invalid arguments. Also, `items.ToArray()` produces an error about implicit conversion of SelectListItem to IEnumerable<SelectListItem>.

Comment: If that doesn't work you need to let me know what obj.Items is!

Comment: I already tried that one too. I think the problem is that obj.Items is of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem> and we are trying to put items of type List<SelectListItem> to it. I also tried casting items by doing `obj.Items = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)items` but it still won't work. :(

Comment: It's on the first code block above. Declared as:
`public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }`

Comment: A List inherits IEnumerable so that doesn't make sense? Just wrote the following to check: List<string> test2 = new List<string>();
   IEnumerable<string> test = test2;

Comment: OK, I think you must have different SelectListItem classes? Check the full namespaces match?

Comment: You're right. That code you asked me to write works. Here's the exact error message I'm getting:

Comment: You're right. That code you asked me to write works. Here's the exact error message I'm getting: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH! I got it! Apparently, I mistakenly wrote `using System.Web.WebPages.Html;` instead of `using System.Web.Mvc;` to declare the IEnumerable<SelectListItem>. Thank you for your help!!!!