# Best Practice for adding List<string> to DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nopcommerce

My controller looks as follow:

```
var _engine = new NopEngine();
            var categoryService = _engine.Resolve<ICategoryService>();
            var allCategory = categoryService.GetAllCategories();

            List<string> ConvertedList = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < allCategory.Count; i++)
            {
                ConvertedList.Add(allCategory[i].Name);
            }

            //fill the viewbag
            ViewBag.CategoryList = ConvertedList;

            return View("Nop.Plugin.Misc.ExportAttributes.Views.MiscExportAttributes.ExportCalculationSheet");
```

So basically I'm filling the ViewBag with a List of strings.

My view looks as follow:

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@model ExportCalculationSheetModel
@using Nop.Plugin.Misc.ExportAttributes.Models;
@using Nop.Web.Framework;
@using Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog;
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table class="adminContent">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <b>Filter op Categorie:</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="adminTitle">
                @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.searchCategory):
            </td>
            <td class="adminData">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.searchCategory, new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoryList, "Name"))
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

This works, the DropDownList gets filled with the correct values. But I don't think that the ViewBag is "Best-Practice", I heard something about using a Model to select the List from, I already added a reference to the model in the view:

```
@model ExportCalculationSheetModel
```

How can I fill the list at the model class and use it in my view?

I already tried to fill the model class the following way, but that didn't work out:

```
public List<string> AllCategories
        {
            get
            {
                return AllCategories;
            }
            set
            {
                var _engine = new NopEngine();
                var categoryService = _engine.Resolve<ICategoryService>();
                var allCategory = categoryService.GetAllCategories();

                List<string> ConvertedList = new List<string>();

                for (int i = 0; i < allCategory.Count; i++)
                {
                    ConvertedList.Add(allCategory[i].Name);
                }
                AllCategories = ConvertedList;
            }
        }
```

**So the two primary questions are:**

1. How do I fill the list at the model page?
2. How do I connect the list at my model page to the dropdownlist at my view?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1710864.aspx/1

Comment: If you are looking for a review of your code, and you don't have a specific problem (i.e something is not necessarily broke), there is a StackExchange site specifically for it: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing `DropDownListFor` needs is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (i.e., that could be a list/collection/queryable/etc.). The problem right now is that you simply have a list `string` instead of `SelectListItem`. That's easy remedied with a little LINQ-fu:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.searchCategory, Model.AllCategories.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m, Text = m }))
```

However, the better approach would be to simply have `AllCategories` return a list of `SelectListItem`s off-the-bat (assuming it's only being used for populating the dropdown list).

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> allCategories;
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllCategories
{
    get
    {
        if (allCategories == null)
        {
            var _engine = new NopEngine();
            var categoryService = _engine.Resolve<ICategoryService>();

            allCategories = categoryService.GetAllCategories().Select(m =>
                new SelectListItem { Value = m.Name, Text = m.Name });
        }

        return allCategories;
    }

    // You don't need a setter
}
```

The first time `AllCategories` is accessed, the associated private variable, `allCategories`, will be null, so your service spins up and the list of categories is fetched. `Select` is used to cast the returned categories into a collection of `SelectListItem`s. If you category has something like an `Id` property, you should use that for `Value` instead of `Name`. Any subsequent accesses of `AllCategories` will simply return the value stored in the private without hitting the database again.

**Bonus Pro Tip**

If you actually do need to use a for loop for something like this, you don't need to create a new list, add items to the list in the loop, and then return that list. It's easier to just use `yield`. For example:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Numbers
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! And thanks for the tip, i will definitly use that:)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
List<string> ConvertedList = new List<string>();
```

to

```
List<SelectList> ConvertedList = new List<SelectList>();
```

do not need for loop . you can directly add the database return list values to `ConvertedList`

look this sample's
[Binding Data To DropDownList MVC Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226780/binding-data-to-dropdownlist-mvc-razor)

here is a good [sample](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/128/Get-The-Drop-On-ASP.NET-MVC-DropDownLists)

Comment: I use the for-loop, to filter out the Name value from List<ICategoryService> which is an interface, so I will have a List of strings, should I convert that list to a <SelectList>?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this:

Starting with a Dictionary in the Model

```
    public class YourOptions
    {
        public Dictionary<int, string> Option { get; set; }

        public YourOptions()
        {
            Option = new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                //Here you should put your code, this is an example
                { 0, "Option 1"},
                { 1, "Option 2"},
                { 2, "Option 3"},
                { 3, "Option 4"},
                { 4, "Option 5"},
                //Here you should put your code, this is an example
            };

    }
```

In the View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Option.Keys,
                         new SelectList(
                             Model.Option, 
                             "Key", 
                             "Value"))
```

Sorry for my bad english! I hope this help you!